# Possible to change the space encoding for JQueryUI Autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, encoding, jquery-ui-autocomplete

By default JQueryUI's Autocomplete will encode spaces as "+". My remote source expects the encoding as "%20". Is it possible to change the way spaces are encoded?

Comment: An example to play with will be awesome. Could you post an example in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Vega: Not really sure it needs one as JQuery-UI's Autocomplete encodes spaces as '+' by default.

Comment: If you are using `source: "http://example.com/"`, try to make request to server manually by using `source: function(request, successCallback) { $.ajax(...).done(successCallback); }`.

Comment: @Regent: yeah, that ends up not solving it. Spaces still come out to '+'.

Comment: Have you just added your string as part of request url or as `data: your_str`? If so, it's not surprising that it ends up with `+`. You should manually "prepare" string (by replacing " " with "%20") and send it as `data: prepared_str` with setting `processData: false`

Comment: Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/4jxbut39/) to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: That's clearer. Make it an answer & the bounty is yours.

Comment: I'm glad that this code was helpful for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is:

- to make autocomplete request to server manually using `$.ajax()`
- to prepare manually sent data by replacing " " with "%20"
- to prevent default processing of sent data using `processData: false`

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/4jxbut39/).

```
<input id="test">

$('#test').autocomplete
({
    source: autocompleteRequest
});

function autocompleteRequest(request, response)
{
    var inputString = request.term;
    var preparedString = inputString.replace(/\s/g, "%20");
    $.ajax({
        url: "test/",
        data: "str=" + preparedString,
        processData: false
    }).success(function(data)
    {
        response(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try using **encodeURIComponent(sample)** before making a server request,

Refer: http://nebsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/03/jquery-autocomplete-encoding-issue.html

Comment: That ends up double encoding things & "Michael Valentine" ends up as "Michael%2520Valentine"

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate your problem, but as ManoNamo said, your problem is probably just the way you send the data over to your server. Both encodeURI and encodeURIComponent will suit your purposes. See below a working example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jqueryui.com/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript KABAM",
      "ActionScript",
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      change: function(event, ui) {
        console.dir(encodeURIComponent(ui.item.value));
        console.dir(encodeURI($("input#tags").val()));
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That ends up double encoding things & "Michael Valentine" ends up as "Michael%2520Valentine"